# Python: print variable together from different for loop

Tags: python

```
for synset in wn.synsets(wordstr):
    len_lemma_names = len (synset.lemma_names)
    #print len_lemma_names, synset.lemma_names
    count_lemma = count_lemma + len_lemma_names
for synset_scores in swn_senti_synset:
    count_synset = count_synset + 1
    #print count_synset, synset_scores
```

I am trying to print len_lemma_names in front of count_synset but it did not work. Is there any way possible for printing them together? Thank you...

Comment: Are `wn.synsets(wordstr)` and `swn_senti_synset` always the same length?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Which line are you trying to print it in? And where are the `count_*` variables defined? And what do they all mean?

Comment: Is there a relation between `synsets` and `swn_senti_synset` - or do you always want to print ALL `len_lemma_names` for each `synset_score`?

Comment: @Gjallar There is no relationship between synsets and swn_senti_synset. Yes I want to print Len_lemma_names for each synset_score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are wanting to iterate over the two, together. If this is the case, you want to use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), or to avoid turning it all into one big list at once, [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).

```
from itertools import izip

for synset, synset_scores in izip(wn.synsets(wordstr), swn_senti_synset):
    # Now you can deal with both at once in this loop.
    len_lemma_names = len(synset.lemma_names)
    count_lemma += len_lemma_names
    count_synset += 1
    # Mix to taste.
    print len_lemma_names, count_synset
```

Note that the `count_synset` part may be better done with [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) (I don't know its initial value or whether you're wanting to use it outside this code).

Comment: Thank you, that takes me over 10k :-)